# Error x509 (Kubernetes) certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes

I was installing **Mehsery** on **Kubernetes** and this error occured:

```bash
⣽ Deploying Meshery on KubernetesError: failed to start Meshery
See https://docs.meshery.io/reference/mesheryctl/system for usage details
: could not install meshery server: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://192.168.49.2:8443/version": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
could not install meshery-operator: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://192.168.49.2:8443/version": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

This is the configuration of my `config` file for **kubernetes**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/yana/.minikube/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Wed, 12 Jul 2023 21:23:41 IST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.30.1
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://192.168.49.2:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Wed, 12 Jul 2023 21:23:41 IST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.30.1
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/yana/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/yana/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

The Meshery should be installed but I don't know why this error is coming I also refereed to Kubernetes docs but didn't find anything that can help me.